# What is the purpose of MAXVALUE of an Oracle sequence?

Tags: oracle, sequence

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571) is clear:

`MAXVALUE`: Specify the maximum value the sequence can generate.

And the error message is clear, too:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE smax START WITH 1 MAXVALUE 2;

SELECT smax.nextval FROM dual;
1

SELECT smax.nextval FROM dual;
2

SELECT smax.nextval FROM dual;
ORA-08004: SEQUENCE SMAX.NEXTVAL exceeds MAXVALUE and cannot be instantiated
```

But, what is the **purpose** of `MAXVALUE`? Has anybody ever used it for production purposes? Of the many sequences I've seen, the `MAXVALUE` is either not used or set to an arbitrary high value which seemed high enough to be never reached.

The combination of `MINVALUE`, `MAXVALUE` and `CYCLE` would make sense, though, but is it found in the wild, i.e. is somebody actually using it?

Comment: The functionality exists to set a maximum value, either to enforce some business rule or just to allow the sequence to cycle back around to the start. It seems self-explanatory to me. Is this a poll to see what people are using it for?

Comment: No, not a poll. I simply cannot see a possible real life use case for capping or cycling a sequence.

Comment: Nonetheless, that is its purpose.

Comment: I might have bumped into a language issue here (not being a native speaker as you might have guessed). So the purpose of the keyword `MAXVALUE` is to cap a sequence, but what is the purpose of a capped sequence? By now I believe it looked like a good idea when they created Oracle, but I severely doubt that anybody ever has used it for real.

Comment: Well, there are many features I have never seen used (Java Stored Procedures, object tables, the MODEL clause, Editioning, Apex). In this case there is a logical completeness to allowing a sequence to be defined in terns of start, increment, end, whether to loop etc.

Comment: For some of them I can imagine an use case, but not for a capped sequence. Interestingly, your "seen feature list" is different to mine, and I hope that is true for other stackoverflow users, and that's why I posted the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is part of the 2003 SQL Standard, so it isn't really an Oracle specific question.

I'd mostly expect a MAXVALUE to be used with a CYCLE, but there is the potential that additional intervention (eg code change to switch a prefix) is required so you wouldn't want it to cycle automatically.

There may be a physical limit (eg the value has to fit in 6 digits) or a conversion imposed limit (eg has to fit in two bytes). Whenever I've worked with a system with such a limit, we've avoided sequences as we don't want any unused digits going to waste through caching, failed transactions etc.

Answer (score -1):

One of the use cases of Sequence numbers could be to have a unique ID, that can be used by the application (for example sequence number along with Joulian date to generate Journal Key) To minimize the collision of numbers we would have a large number set for `MAXVALUE`

Without a MAXVALUE the sequence would keep getting incremented, and with a value set, it would cycle through once the MAXVALUE is reached.

```
Example: 
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 10
    MAXVALUE 100
the Sequence would go back to 1 once it reaches the value 91
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean with "to minimize the collision of numbers".

Comment: The Journal Key for example should be unique number. We try to append a 4 digit sequence to make it unique and avoid same numbers to be generated to different uses (Assumption is that the number of user transaction is less than 9999 on a give day, if it exceeds the same numbers would cycle trough for the given Julian date)

Comment: OK, a sequence will never generate the same number for different uses. But how is this related with  a large `MAXVALUE`?

Comment: If we don't specify a large enough MAXVALUE, there would be repetition of numbers. We want to avoid it, as much as possible (in an example use case I was referring to)

Comment: No, that's technically wrong, the numbers won't be repeated unless you specify `CYCLE`. "Specify [NOCYCLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571)  to indicate that the sequence cannot generate more values after reaching its maximum or minimum value. This is the default."

Comment: *"Without a MAXVALUE the sequence would keep getting incremented,"*. And that's a good thing.